# .NET Core 3.1 application not building on Azure pipeline anymore (.NET 5)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-core-3.1, .net-5

Until recently our .Net Core 3.1 applications were building and publishing fine on Azure pipelines. But over the last couple of days the build pipelines have started to fail with the error:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): 
Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\ProjectFolder\src\Project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

```
(ResolvePackageAssets target) -> 
  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): 
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\ProjectFolder\src\Project\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp3.1'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp3.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [D:\a\1\s\ProjectFolder\src\Project\Project.csproj]
```

The build pipeline is setup as follows for the solution build step that is failing.

[image: Build configuration - using latest, but setting to VS 2019 also fails.]

Any ideas how to resolve this with the least amount of change?

Comment: BTW, is there a reason for building the app using the Visual Studio tooling, instead of the .NET Core tooling directly? When using `dotnet build`, `dotnet restore` takes place automatically and the `dotnet` command usually works great. Just use the [.NET Core CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> .NET Core 3.1 application not building on Azure pipeline anymore (.NET 5)

Please try to update the `nuget.exe` to the `5.8.0` by the task [NuGet tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops)：

[image]

You could check [this thread](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/msbuild-uses-net-50-sdk-or-net-core-sdks-for-net-f/1252149) for some more details.

Comment: We got the same error (##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): Error NETSDK1005: Assets file ...) started since Friday. We were actually using NuGet 4.4.1 and as per your recommendation I disabled the NuGet 4.4.1 and created a new NuGet tool installer step with the version 5.8.0 just like what you have suggested and the error is gone, the azure pipeline successfully completed the build and deployment. Thanks @Leo Liu-MSFT.

Comment: In my case "Version of NuGet.exe to install" had a predefined value of 4.4.1, I applied the solution  from Leo but forgot to empty that field, it worked after I typed a specific version (5.8.0 worked for me, I suppose you may also leave it blank).

Answer (score 2):

had the same problem with a local build agent

```
error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'project.assets.json' ....
```

Update NuGet.exe to the 5.8.0 version or above

and clearing NuGet cache:

```
dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

[Download Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)

found [here](https://ivanderevianko.com/2020/11/fixed-error-netsdk1005-assets-file-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net48)